# Gloabal Json file shared with many projects in one solution (asp.net core 2.0)

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a solution with many projects:
`Yupii.Games -> Class Library where settings, utilities are shared with projects
Yupii.Games.Web -> Web app
Yupii.Games.Api -> Web api`

I am using mongoDB as database and I have many collections but I want to respect collection name convention for example:
*Monster* (is an entity) to *monsters* the collection name.

I have a json file in Yupii.Games named GlobalSettings.json:

```
"MongoDBCollections": {
"Collections": [
  { "Monster": "monsters" },
  { "User": "users" }
   ...
]}
```

In the Yupii.Games.Api I have something like:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<MongoDbSettings>(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:ConnectionString").Value;
            options.Database = Configuration.GetSection("MongoConnection:Database").Value;

        )}; 

    }
```

How can I reach to GlobalSettings.json -> "MongoDBCollections" -> Collections[] to have also a service for :

```
services.Configure<GlobalSettings>(options =>
        {
            options.Collections = CollectionsConfiguration.GetSection("MongoDBItems:Collections").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        });
```

Then loop to get the associate collection name:

```
var collectionName = typeof(T).Name;

foreach (var collection in CollectionList)
{
    if (collectionName == collection.Key)
          return Database.GetCollection<T>(collection.Value);
}
return Database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
```

I want to be able to do the same in Yupii.Games.Web
Actually, I am able to make every to work fine in a different way but the code and the structure is awful. If any body can show a better and clean way plz.
I am using Visual Studio 2017 asp.net core 2.0
I hope everything is clear...
**UPDATE**
In Yupii.Games.Web one of the method make calls this way:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(RESTVersion + GetCollectionName() + e).Result;
```

and the GetCollectionName():

```
    public string GetCollectionName()
    {
        string collectionName = typeof(T).Name;
        ... // get the collection name by associating the typeof(T)
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Just curious - why are using GlobalSetting.json and not `appSetting.json` that is being read by the application for you? Also i assume web would be your startup project - why not place the file there as your `startup.cs` resides in the web or api

Comment: So if I place MongoDBCollections the Yupii.Games.Api appSettings.json how can I reach it from Yupii.Games.Web ? I don't want to repeat MongoDBCollection json elements in both appSettings.json (Web and Api). I also have Xamarin that makes call with HttpClient.

Comment: which project exactly needs it? I assume it is the web api right? - then place it in that project and on startup.cs read the file and loop over the collection, your web i assume is using the api

Comment: the Api for sure, the others have a common Class Library Yupii.Games.WebHTTP that makes Http calls. (I updated my question). So Web and Xamarin have a Yupii.Games.WebHTTP reference to use the RESTful api.

Comment: Again if the web api has everything it needs and the client simply calls into it , i dont understand why it should be in the web or Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yupii.Games.Api --> Startup.cs
this is what the startup constructor look like:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

        GlobalSettingsConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("GlobalSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"GlobalSettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();
    }
```

Both GlobalSettings json files are in Yupii.Games (Class Library). 
I add a property:

```
public IConfiguration GlobalSettingsConfiguration { get; }
```

then in ConfigureServices:

```
        services.Configure<MongoDbSettings>(options =>
        {
            ...
            options.Collections = GlobalSettingsConfiguration.GetSection("MongoDBItems:Collections").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();      
        });
```

MongoDBSettings class don't have a Collections property but inherit from GlobalSettings.cs in Yupii.Games project

Before I can loop through:

```
"MongoDBItems": {
"Collections": {
  "Monster": "monsters",
  "User": "users",
  "Matrix": "matrices"
}
```

Click right on both GlobalSettings json files --> go to *properties* --> and *copy to Output Directory* should be *copy always*

So now I can loop through the collections :

```
        foreach (var collection in CollectionList)
        {
            if (collectionName == collection.Key)
                return Database.GetCollection<T>(collection.Value);
        }
```

So this is it!
Thanks for helping guys (@Jaya and @BOR4) :)

Comment: I admire your dedication to irregular plurals =)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you avoid reading anything from config. Simply have a generic method where it best suits you that does this:

```
MongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name.ToLower() + "s");
```

This way you never have to update config, you have a naming convention, if you please to change naming convention you have to change it in only 1 place ....

PS I tried to understand your specific problem but after reading several times your question I still wasn't sure what exactly you needed.

Comment: That line of code was my old one because I want to consider the irregular one (matrix -> matrices). Sorry if it's not clear but I'm coming with a solution in a moment... thanks again !